# Explaination of LXFML file contents

Tags: software, cad, ldd

I am interested in writing a game that interprets LXF files into worlds (to create a game such as Lego Universe).  After finding out how to extract the LXFML file from the LXF archive, I need to know how to interpret the contained LXFML file.  Are there any detailed descriptions of how the LXFML format works?

Comment: Note that while LU had a number of LEGO models in it, the world as a whole wasn't made of LEGO elements - the landscape was still a standard "terrain mesh" type of thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The LXFML file is an XML document, and there's an XSD document that you can use to validate any LXFML file, along with a textual description of the tags on the LUGNet forums supplied by the LDD Team a few years ago:

> [LXF files - info and XML schema](http://news.lugnet.com/cad/ldd/?n=140)

The key parts of the LXFML you're going to be interested in start with the `<Scene>` element, which contains one or more `<model>` elements, which in turn contains one or more `<group>` elements, which are made up of `<part>` elements.

The tricky part is getting from a `<part>` element to an actual model:

```
<Part refID="0" name="m3680_turn_plate_2x2__lower_part_0" designID="3680" 
      materialID="1" assemblyID="74340" assemblyRefID="0" 
      angle="0" ax="0" ay="1" az="0" tx="0" ty="0" tz="0" />
```

As you can see, the Design ID corresponds to a LEGO element [part:3680] so you'll need some way to get from those to a suitable model - I recommend taking a look at either:

- [BricksViewer](http://bricksviewer.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) - A Java app for viewing .lxf scene files - also has a brief discussion of the .lxf and .lxfml formats.
- [LDXNA](http://code.google.com/p/ldxna/) - An XNA library for importing LDraw models - it does include an .lxfml document in one of its examples, but I don't recall it using it - however it does show you how to convert the LDraw parts library into a usable format.

Comment: There has been a change in the LXFML file. I didn't check since which version, the change was applied, but LDD 4.3 (Sep-2018) has a different structure. e.g., <Part> is now <Brick> and attributes angle, ax, ay, az, tx, ty, tz are now a single transformation attribute

Comment: Do you remember what ay was?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I believe the `ax`, `ay` and `az` denoted the axis of rotation, and then `tx`, `ty` and `tz` are the "transform" or positional axis.